# express-fileupload:get check size in express js

Tags: node.js, express, file-upload

I am using [this package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-fileupload)
to upload the image into server ,i want to check  the file size before upload but `express-fileupload` doesn't give any information about it

`console.log(req.files.image)`; it returns only the name,data ,and image type

Answer (score 4):

Assuming the name of your file in your HTML file is `image`, `req.files.image.data.length` will give you the buffer length in bytes. See [this Node.js. API Documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_buf_length) for more details. You can then do the math to convert the number of bytes into any thing you want.

This will allow you to get the actual number of bytes independent of filetype and doesn't require using the `mv` function. So you can use this on any file type not just images.

Hopefully this helps!

Answer (score -1):

I think only way to get image info using `express-fileupload` is using `mv` function to move image on server then using `image-size` to get width and height

Comment: The question says "check the file size". Not image width and height. Using the length property of the buffer as described in my answer will give the number of bytes in the buffer.